# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol file not found

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am using Qt6.2.2 in Win10 with VS2019 to build a project that involves using [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) function from Windows API:

```
#include <windows.h>

// major codes omitted

hFrameEvent = camera.GetFrameEvent();
```

Here `camera` is an instance of [C1394Camera](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eiwan/1394/) for image collection.

```
dwRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,&hFrameEvent,FALSE,timeout,QS_ALLINPUT); //MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is called
```

Building the project gives the error `LNK2019 error unresolved external symbol __imp_MsgWaitForMultipleObjects referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ...`

Does the error mean that the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is not properly used or something wrong with my windows SDK or the `camera` pointer?

Comment: this mean that you not include User32.lib to linker input

Comment: How to include the lib file? Do I need to configure some environment paths or qt .pro file?

Comment: You need to link to it. If you're using a .pro file, then you need to configure it in there.

Comment: what commands to add in a .pro file? Thanks!

Comment: I add "LIBS += -luser32" in the file. It seems to the solution.

Comment: @RbMm can you educate me what the User32.lib is typically used for? I did some similar projects using earlier versions of Qt and Visual studio, which worked but without explicitly including user32.lib

Comment: In the very documentation of the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` API function you have linked in your question, there is Requirements section at the end, in which there is mentioned: "**Library** User32.lib". This tells you what library to link against when using this API function.